# Printing Quote Through Loops C++

Tags: c++, loops

my knowledge of c++ is pitiful. I've been stumped on this simple problem for a long time and would just a point to the right the direction. The basis of the program is to have the user chose a number 1-5 and then based on their decision print out a quote that many times. So if they chose the number 4 it will display the quote 4 times.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int PickNumber()
{
    int i;
    cout << "Please Enter a Number From 1 to 5:";
    cin >> i;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        cout << "Congrats!";
    }
    return i;
}
int main()
{
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try calling the function you wrote.

Comment: You are not calling the function `PickNumber()` in your `main`. Put `PickNumber();` before the `_getch();`

Comment: try this for your main: `int main() {
    _getch();
    PickNumber();
    return 0;
}`

Comment: @Rietty Wow... It was right in front of my face and I never saw it. Thank you guys.

Comment: Quote marks in C++ and most other language indicate a string literal, so you should refer to them as "strings". They have nothing to do with quotes in English writing.

Comment: Note: If you ate merely using `_getch` to prevent an IDE from closing the program console when the program exits, consider placing a debugger breakpoint on the final line of the program instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add an answer to this question already solved by @molbdnilo, @Rietty and @Gox: the `PickNumber()` function is not called in the `main` function.

The `PickNumber()` call just needs to be added to the `main` function.

```
int main() {
    PickNumber();
    return 0;
}
```